# How to determine which cell was tapped by the user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with two cells which are created from an array. Once the user taps on the first cell, I want to call a method and when the user taps on the second one I want to bring up another ViewController.

I tried to use this method to react on the tap event:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.extraMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"\nCell at Index: %@ clicked.\n", indexPath);
}
```

Here is the log:

```
Cell at Index: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} clicked. (First item clicked)
Cell at Index: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000008016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1} clicked. (Second item clicked)
```

How do I determine which cell was tapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the index path to determine which cell was tapped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"First cell tapped!");
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Second cell tapped!");
    }

    // Deselect the row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you I figured it out by the time you responded.